# How to make QTP recognise different application windows which are opened at run time

Tags: identification

I am testing an application that pulls up different document of different document types ( like doc, xls,ppt,pdf,mp3 e.tc.) problem is when an document is open, the respective application is launched ( like MS WORD, MS excel, zip,Adobe) . How to make QTP recognise the application that is used to open the respective document, I need to save the document after viewing it thr automation.